# "zooming" and "page-zoom" should be synonyms for "zoom"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

### [zoom](/questions/tagged/zoom) (1,349 questions tagged)

> Zooming is the act of enlarging something (a document, an image, a
> map) to view it in greater detail.

### [zooming](/questions/tagged/zooming) (277 questions tagged)

> Zooming in graphical user interfaces is a facility that allows users
> to change the scale of the viewed area in order to see more detail or
> less. Often, there is a facility that allows the user to move the
> zoomed area with respect to the overall item being viewed.

### [page-zoom](/questions/tagged/page-zoom) (23 question tagged)

*No tag wiki available.*

Comment: Not an expert, but I believe [tag:page-zoom] refers quite specifically to the feature of some browsers whereby zoom isn't just an across-the-board visual enlargement, but something 'cleverer'. This is different from the concept of zooming in general.